# Magento 2.4.4 error ASSING NULL TO PARAMETER OF TYPE STRING IS DEPRECATED

Tags: magento2.4.4

I am using the latest version of porto theme and magento 2.4.4.
I'm having a problem right now,

```
php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
Deploy using quick strategy
Error happened during deploy process: Deprecated Functionality: pathinfo(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($path) of type string is deprecated in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/PreProcessor/FileNameResolver.php on line 44

Execution time: 0.13012981414795
```

Can you help me?

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revise `/vendor/magento/framework/App/Utility/Files.php`
as follow:

```
if (!$files) {
    $result[] = [
                    $themeArea,
                    $themePackage->getVendor() . '/' . $themePackage->getName(),
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    ''
                ];
}
```

Comment: that solution works ,

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the below code in the core Magento file for a quick fix.

FilePath: vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/PreProcessor/FileNameResolver.php

Line No: 42

$extension = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
to
$extension = pathinfo($fileName ?? "", PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

Thanks